# Python - thread`s target is a method of an object

Tags: python, multithreading

I have the following code :

Consumer.py

```
class Consumer():

    def __init__(self,q):
        print("Consumer")
        self.q = q


    def consumeItem(self,num):
        while  not self.q.empty():
            print(self.q.get())
```

Producer.py

```
class Producer():
    def __init__(self,q):
        self.q = q
        print("Producer")

    def generateItem(self):
        for i in range(1,100):
            print("produce item ",i)
            self.q.put(i)
```

main :

```
import queue

import threading
q=queue.Queue()

from Producer import Producer
from Consumer import Consumer

producer=Producer(q)
consumer=Consumer(q)


t1=threading.Thread(target=producer.generateItem(),name="thread1")
t2=threading.Thread(target=consumer.consumeItem(),name="thread2",args=(1,))
#t2=threading.Thread(target=consumer.consumeItem(),name="thread2",args=(consumer,1))
#t2=threading.Thread(target=consumer.consumeItem(),name="thread2",kwargs={'self': consumer,'num': 2})

t1.start()
t2.start()
```

I keep getting the same error :

```
t2=threading.Thread(target=consumer.consumeItem(),name="thread2",args=(1))
TypeError: consumeItem() missing 1 required positional argument: 'num'
```

As you can see in the code, I tried a few options to initialize the second thread. The first thread works like expected but the second one isn't working.

Any idea why the first one works while the second isn't?

Comment: You have to use a number to the consumeItem() function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The target should be a function, not a function call, so use this instead:

```
t1 = threading.Thread(target = producer.generateItem, name = "thread1")
t2 = threading.Thread(target = consumer.consumeItem, name = "thread2", args = (1,))

# function names without parenthesis
```

Comment: First of all thanks. It seems that the consumer is working faster than the producer and then it stops because the q is empty. However, it was empty for less than 1 second and then again number was inserted but the thread of the consumer finished. how can I handle that situation ?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you want to put the consumer in a loop with a sleep in case the queue is empty and implement some signal to stop it, like a "stop" message in the queue

```
    def consumeItem(self,num):
        while True:
            if self.q.empty(): time.sleep(1)
        else:
            m = self.q.get()
            if m == EXITMESSAGE:
                break
            else:
                print(m)
```

This consumer will wait forever until a message arrives and will die when it receives the EXITMESSAGE